# Cannot add duplicate source reference VBA/Excel - Consolidation of multiple Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

All sheets are contained in the same workbook.
`Sheet1` is to be the summary sheet for consolidation.
There are a dynamic number of worksheets beyond `Sheet1`. 
I have a set range of data from each source data sheet after `Sheet1`:

```
C54:H56 (a 3x6 grid of cells)
```

This data needs to be consolidated into a single `3x6` area on the summary sheet (`Sheet1`).
I am not referring to just copying data but rather the actual consolidation function in Excel.

The error I am receiving, at the moment, is:

> Run-time error '1004': Cannot add duplicate source reference

I have tried many different variations and always end up with either syntax, subscript out of range issues or the current one, as noted above.

When I examine the contents of `ConsolidationArray`, the correct sheet names and ranges are being captured. However, I cannot actually pass these to the consolidation function itself and/or have them properly implemented.

Code:

```
Sub WorkseetParsingLoopToGetData()
     Dim I as Integer
     Dim WS_Count as Integer
     Dim ConsolidationArray as Variant

     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count 'last worksheet
     ReDim ConsolidationArray(2 to WS_Count) 'Array to be Sheet2 to last worksheet

     For I = 2 to WS_Count
          ConsolidationArray(I) = Worksheets(I).Name & "!C54:H56"
     Next I
     Sheets("Summary").Range("J4").Consolidate sources:=(ConsolidationArray), Function:=xlAverage
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ConsolidationArray` needs to be zero based and the range  reference strings in R1C1-style notation.

```
Sub WorkseetParsingLoopToGetData()
     Dim i As Integer
     Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim ConsolidationArray()

     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count 'last worksheet
     ReDim ConsolidationArray(WS_Count - 2) 'Array to be Sheet2 to last worksheet

     For i = 2 To WS_Count
          ConsolidationArray(i - 2) = Worksheets(i).Name & "!R54C3:R56C8" '"!C54:H56"
     Next i
     Sheets("Summary").Range("J4").Consolidate Sources:=(ConsolidationArray), Function:=xlAverage
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The solution was successful. I understand my two errors now--which is an even greater help than the raw functional code.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer.  I'm happy that it helped.